# clang error using Unity Cloud build

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error when building using unities cloud build.  I added a PostBuildProcessor script to my editor folder.  I posted my current OnPostprocessBuild function.  any help would be appreciated.

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

.

```
    // a normal post process method which is executed by Unity
    [PostProcessBuild]
    public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
    {
#if UNITY_CLOUD_BUILD && UNITY_IOS

            Debug.Log("[UCB Demos] OnPostprocessBuildiOS");
            string projPath = path + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";

            PBXProject proj = new PBXProject ();
            proj.ReadFromString (File.ReadAllText (projPath));

            string target = proj.TargetGuidByName ("Unity-iPhone");
           // proj.AddBuildProperty (target, "OTHER_LDFLAGS", "-all_load"); 
            // Set a custom link flag
            proj.AddBuildProperty (target, "OTHER_LDFLAGS", "-ObjC");

            File.WriteAllText (projPath, proj.WriteToString ());

#endif
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I added the output log of the failure.

```
       [xcode] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
3255:        [xcode] Ld build/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/dev normal armv7
3256:        [xcode]     cd /BUILD_PATH/fixuis.mothership-dev.default-ios/temp.fFaeKr
3257:        [xcode]     export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
3258:        [xcode] Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
3259:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerSeekToTime", referenced from:
3260:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSeekToTime_m536131008 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3261:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Rewind_m3115699017 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3262:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Seek_m724302437 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3263:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSeekToTime_m536131008 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3264:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Rewind_m3115699017 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3265:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Seek_m724302437 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3266:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSeekToTime_m536131008)
3267:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerClose", referenced from:
3268:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerClose_m3901226378 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3269:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_CloseVideo_m3052283761 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3270:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerClose_m3901226378 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3271:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_CloseVideo_m3052283761 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3272:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerClose_m3901226378)
3273:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerOpenURL", referenced from:
3274:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerOpenURL_m2818846069 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3275:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerOpenURL_m2818846069 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3276:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerOpenURL_m2818846069)
3277:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerPause", referenced from:
3278:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerPause_m1893267916 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3279:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Pause_m4028410762 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3280:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Stop_m2449956880 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3281:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerPause_m1893267916 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3282:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Pause_m4028410762 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3283:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Stop_m2449956880 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3284:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerPause_m1893267916)
3285:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerRelease", referenced from:
3286:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerRelease_m3716667600 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3287:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Dispose_m960040115 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3288:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerRelease_m3716667600 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3289:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Dispose_m960040115 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3290:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerRelease_m3716667600)
3291:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerSetVolume", referenced from:
3292:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSetVolume_m2245104075 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3293:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_SetVolume_m3069742843 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3294:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSetVolume_m2245104075 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3295:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_SetVolume_m3069742843 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3296:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSetVolume_m2245104075)
3297:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerIsMuted", referenced from:
3298:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerIsMuted_m3147131357 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3299:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsMuted_m1402367249 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3300:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerIsMuted_m3147131357 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3301:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsMuted_m1402367249 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3302:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerIsMuted_m3147131357)
3303:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerSetLooping", referenced from:
3304:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSetLooping_m4225175861 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3305:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_SetLooping_m794236865 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3306:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSetLooping_m4225175861 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3307:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_SetLooping_m794236865 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3308:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSetLooping_m4225175861)
3309:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerGetVolume", referenced from:
3310:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetVolume_m428532670 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3311:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_GetVolume_m323712368 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3312:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetVolume_m428532670 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3313:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_GetVolume_m323712368 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3314:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetVolume_m428532670)
3315:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerPlay", referenced from:
3316:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerPlay_m1271709648 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3317:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Play_m2356272834 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3318:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerPlay_m1271709648 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3319:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Play_m2356272834 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3320:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerPlay_m1271709648)
3321:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerGetTextureHandle", referenced from:
3322:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetTextureHandle_m4192545698 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3323:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Render_m2853164388 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3324:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetTextureHandle_m4192545698 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3325:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Render_m2853164388 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3326:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetTextureHandle_m4192545698)
3327:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerGetHandle", referenced from:
3328:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetHandle_m2848911770 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3329:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Render_m2853164388 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3330:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Dispose_m960040115 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3331:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetHandle_m2848911770 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3332:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Render_m2853164388 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3333:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Dispose_m960040115 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3334:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetHandle_m2848911770)
3335:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerTextureSizeHasChanged", referenced from:
3336:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerTextureSizeHasChanged_m2581288136 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3337:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerTextureSizeHasChanged_m2581288136 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3338:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerTextureSizeHasChanged_m2581288136)
3339:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerSetMuted", referenced from:
3340:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSetMuted_m4093970018 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3341:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_MuteAudio_m1468986184 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3342:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSetMuted_m4093970018 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3343:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_MuteAudio_m1468986184 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3344:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerSetMuted_m4093970018)
3345:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerGetStatus", referenced from:
3346:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetStatus_m1423407501 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3347:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_CanPlay_m507429140 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3348:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsSeeking_m3026061584 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3349:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsPlaying_m319021524 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3350:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsPaused_m928616938 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3351:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsFinished_m244585838 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3352:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetStatus_m1423407501 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3353:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_CanPlay_m507429140 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3354:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsSeeking_m3026061584 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3355:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsPlaying_m319021524 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3356:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsPaused_m928616938 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3357:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsFinished_m244585838 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3358:        [xcode]       ...
3359:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetStatus_m1423407501)
3360:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerGetNominalFrameRate", referenced from:
3361:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetNominalFrameRate_m2554337758 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3362:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetNominalFrameRate_m2554337758 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3363:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetNominalFrameRate_m2554337758)
3364:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerIsLooping", referenced from:
3365:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerIsLooping_m1486189290 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3366:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsLooping_m3469823076 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3367:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerIsLooping_m1486189290 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3368:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IsLooping_m3469823076 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3369:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerIsLooping_m1486189290)
3370:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerGetFrameCount", referenced from:
3371:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetFrameCount_m3702155616 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3372:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_GetTextureFrameCount_m354653567 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3373:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetFrameCount_m3702155616 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3374:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_GetTextureFrameCount_m354653567 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3375:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetFrameCount_m3702155616)
3376:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerGetCurrentTime", referenced from:
3377:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetCurrentTime_m1812350801 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3378:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_GetCurrentTimeMs_m116850872 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3379:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetCurrentTime_m1812350801 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3380:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_GetCurrentTimeMs_m116850872 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3381:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetCurrentTime_m1812350801)
3382:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerGetFrameRate", referenced from:
3383:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetFrameRate_m3749772650 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3384:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_GetVideoPlaybackRate_m4133902914 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3385:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetFrameRate_m3749772650 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3386:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_GetVideoPlaybackRate_m4133902914 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3387:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetFrameRate_m3749772650)
3388:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerGetTextureSize", referenced from:
3389:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetTextureSize_m1311681256 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3390:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetTextureSize_m1311681256 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3391:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetTextureSize_m1311681256)
3392:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerGetDuration", referenced from:
3393:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetDuration_m3518134363 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3394:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_GetDurationMs_m734793264 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3395:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetDuration_m3518134363 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3396:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_GetDurationMs_m734793264 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3397:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerGetDuration_m3518134363)
3398:        [xcode]   "_AVPPluginRegister", referenced from:
3399:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Initialise_m3544296389 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3400:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPluginRegister_m289834245 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3401:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Initialise_m3544296389 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3402:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPluginRegister_m289834245 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3403:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPluginRegister_m289834245)
3404:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerOpenFile", referenced from:
3405:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerOpenFile_m72782334 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3406:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerOpenFile_m72782334 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3407:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerOpenFile_m72782334)
3408:        [xcode]   "_AVPGetVersion", referenced from:
3409:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPGetVersion_m1016144724 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3410:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPGetVersion_m1016144724 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3411:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPGetVersion_m1016144724)
3412:        [xcode]   "_AVPGetRenderEventFunc", referenced from:
3413:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPGetRenderEventFunc_m4179615574 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3414:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IssuePluginEvent_m2085526101 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3415:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPGetRenderEventFunc_m4179615574 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3416:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_IssuePluginEvent_m2085526101 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3417:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPGetRenderEventFunc_m4179615574)
3418:        [xcode]   "_AVPPluginSetDebugLogFunction", referenced from:
3419:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Initialise_m3544296389 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3420:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPluginSetDebugLogFunction_m3413302601 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3421:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_Initialise_m3544296389 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3422:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPluginSetDebugLogFunction_m3413302601 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3423:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPluginSetDebugLogFunction_m3413302601)
3424:        [xcode]   "_AVPPluginInitialise", referenced from:
3425:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPluginInitialise_m666658777 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3426:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPluginInitialise_m666658777 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3427:        [xcode]      (maybe you meant: _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPluginInitialise_m666658777)
3428:        [xcode]   "_AVPPlayerNew", referenced from:
3429:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer__ctor_m3974284790 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3430:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerNew_m3843616605 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3431:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer__ctor_m3974284790 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3432:        [xcode]       _OSXMediaPlayer_AVPPlayerNew_m3843616605 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
3433:        [xcode] ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Comment: Any third party plugin? If there are any, please list them

Comment: The plugin it seems to be having issues with is called AVProProplayer

Answer (score 1):

This error most likely means that you have some [DllImport("__Internal")] extern funtions in Unity that cannot find the corresponding function in C++ side in iOS project. Linking must have nothing to do with postprocessing in Unity. My guess you just have to check the log and find what the linking problems is, usually the name of the function that failed to link is there.